# modal form popup in angular js

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I want modal form popup but it is not appearing. when I am doing inspect element
 it says that $(...)modal is not a function.
Controller:

```
AuthService.createAdmin(data, function (response) {
    if (response.data.success == true) {
        $location.path('/superAdmin');
    } else if (response.data.success == false && response.data.errorCode == 100) {
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    } else {
        $location.path('/superAdmin');
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Info</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">

            <p>The email address {{email}} already exists</p>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="handleBack()" class="btn btn-default" id="cancel" type="button">OK</button>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: $('#myModal').show() ??

Comment: not working #Simon Pertersen

Comment: check your bootstrap css class. This is fade issue. This is open but i think not show.

Comment: Create a codepen about this that would help?

Comment: Why don't you use Angular UI bootstrap or Angular strap?

Comment: you get the error `$('#myModal') is not a function` as ,I suppose you, haven't included jquery in your index.html.You can also use angular.element('#myModal') instead.That may help remove the current error but I dont think that this would actually show a modal

Answer (score 0):

you want to use angularjs.You must change the HTML body and add controller.Following code is modal form popup sample in an angularjs.

Html Body part:

```
<div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3 class="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="item in items">
                    <a href="#" ng-click="$event.preventDefault(); selected.item = item">{{ item }}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            Selected: <b>{{ selected.item }}</b>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
            <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </script>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()">Open me!</button>
</div>
```

Controller part:

```
angular.module('modalSample').controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModal, $log) {

  $scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

  $scope.animationsEnabled = true;

  $scope.open = function (size) {

    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
      size: size,
      resolve: {
        items: function () {
          return $scope.items;
        }
      }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
      $scope.selected = selectedItem;
    }, function () {
      $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
  };


});


angular.module('modalSample').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance, items) {

  $scope.items = items;
  $scope.selected = {
    item: $scope.items[0]
  };

  $scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
});
```